# Xcode 5.0.1 User defined Build Settings won't work anymore

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build-settings

I'v got a problem with Xcode 5.0.1 and OSX 10.9Xcode 5.0.1 
The User defined Build Settings won't work anymore

---

### Example declaration:

```
QTDIR
Debug
        Any Arch | Any iOS Simulator -> /Applications/Qt/5.dev/clang-ios-i386/
        Any Arch | Any iOS           -> /Applications/Qt/5.dev/clang-ios-arm/
    Release
        Any Arch | Any iOS Simulator -> /Applications/Qt/5.dev/clang-ios-i386/
        Any Arch | Any iOS           -> /Applications/Qt/5.dev/clang-ios-arm/
```

### Xcode 5.0.0 behavior at iOS Simulator:

```
Header Include: 
    $(QTDIR)include -> Result: /Applications/Qt/5.dev/clang-ios-i386/include
```

### Xcode 5.0.1 behavior at iOS Simulator

```
Header Include: 
    $(QTDIR)include -> Result:
```

As you can see, the  variable is not resolved.
What can i do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fieWN.png